# How can I get footnotes and paragraphs from Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have code to get paragraphs from a .doc file in Apache POI, but I'd like to get footnotes also. Also, is this the only way to get paragraphs?

Code so far:

```
    InputStream stream = ...
    HWPFDocument document = new HWPFDocument(stream);
    Range range = document.getRange();

    StyleSheet stylesheet = document.getStyleSheet();

    for (int i = 0; i < range.numParagraphs(); i++) {
        Paragraph paragraph = range.getParagraph(i);

        String text = paragraph.text();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this...

```
WordExtractor extractor = new WordExtractor(document);
paragraphs.addAll(Arrays.asList(extractor.getParagraphText()) ); 
footnotes.addAll(Arrays.asList(extractor.getFootnoteText()) );
extractor.close();
```